# Remove scrollbar from android support design navigation drawer?

Tags: android, scrollbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport

I just updated the support design library from 22.2.1 to 23.0.1 and immediately noticed the presence of a scrollbar in the navigation drawer. I tried to use

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

But that didn't fix it. Is there any other way to remove the scrollbar?

Comment: May I ask if you found a recent article on how to implement the navigation drawer ? Lots of articles are at least a year old.

Comment: @StephaneEybert I just downloaded the Cheesesquare example by Chris Banes from Github and copied it from there

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unfortunately the scrollbar is set in the `NavigationMenuView` layout not in the `NavigationView`, for this reason if you use `android:scrollbars="none"` the scrollbar is still present.

You can do it programmatically calling this method:

```
private void disableNavigationViewScrollbars(NavigationView navigationView) {
    if (navigationView != null) {
        NavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (NavigationMenuView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
        if (navigationMenuView != null) {
            navigationMenuView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use following style in your style.xml

```
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/transparent</item>
if you don't have a transparent color defined in colors.xml, use the android library "transparent" with: <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this in Kotlin, hope it will be a help.
first, create different fragments and any navigation you want to after that create a function which will be used to load fragments into the activity.

```
    when (item.getItemId()) {
            R.id.home -> {
                //this is the name of the method I am using for adding fragments 
                //with bottom navigation bar you can use it with any type o navigation.
                loadFragment(getString(R.string.home_fragment), HomeFragment());
                appBar.title = "Home"
                return true
            }
            R.id.jobs -> {
                loadFragment(getString(R.string.jobs_fragment), JobsFragment());
                appBar.title = "Jobs"
                return true
            }
```

after that here is the method

```
        private fun loadFragment(tag: String,loadFragment: Fragment) {
           val fManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction()
            val fragment = fManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)

            if (fragment == null) {
                fTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_main, loadFragment,tag);
            } else { // re-use the old fragment
                fTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_main, fragment, tag);
            }

            fTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            fTransaction.commit();

        }
```

first  val fragment = fManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) this will search if the fragment is already loaded then else statement will be executed and the preloaded fragment will be displayed but if not 
then **loadFragment** parameter we passed contains the fragment you want to load then if statement will be executed which will load the passed fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in apptheme in style :

`<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>`